# Why is DOCSIS 4.0 implementing weak security protocols?

Tags: encryption, network, network-access-control

So I had a look at the latest DOCSIS 4.0 Security Implementation paper here

https://www.cablelabs.com/technologies/docsis-4-0-technology

I found that they’re implementing SHA -1 and 3DES for security. I mean, why?
Surely SHA-256 and AES would be a better choice and AES would be faster in GCM than 3DES to implement over a network too.

Does anyone have an idea why (tinfoil hats removed) these protocols were chosen?

Additionally, DH PKI using only 2048 or less is stated. To be quantum safe, surely we should be looking at expanding this to 4096 or using elliptic curve where possible?

Comment: Compatibility with existing hardware comes to mind? It's a _really_ weak excuse for using known insecure security protocols, but it's by far the most common one.

Comment: *"Additionally, DH PKI using only 2048 or less is stated. To be quantum safe, surely we should be looking at expanding this to 4096 or using elliptic curve where possible?"* - Quantum safe is not a problem which is expected to be addressed by DOCSIS 4.0. Hellm even TLS 1.3 is not quantum safe. And neither DH>2048 nor elliptic curves are quantum safe either. Also, the standard actually supports AES too.